Can we do group Texting in Conversions using Inteliquent
I'm currently using Twilio's group texting feature in Conversations, but I need to switch to using Inteliquent for the same functionality. I've done some research but haven't been able to find clear guidance or examples on how to implement group texting with Inteliquent.
Has anyone managed to achieve this, or can someone point me in the right direction? Specifically, I'm looking for:

Steps or documentation on setting up group texting with Inteliquent.
Any code examples or API references that could help with this transition.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
